# ¿Como asignar una llave primaria compuesta como llave foranea en otra tabla con MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

Lo que pasa es que tengo una llave primaria compuesta en una tabla y esa llave debe ser foránea en otra tabla. Alguien podría ayudarme porfavor?

Ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE `detallehorario` (
  `Id_Grupo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Dia` varchar(15) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `HoraEntrada` time NOT NULL,
  `HoraSalida` time NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id_Grupo`,`Dia`),
  KEY `Id_Grupo_idx` (`Id_Grupo`),
  CONSTRAINT `Id_Grupo` FOREIGN KEY (`Id_Grupo`) REFERENCES `grupo` (`Id_Grupo`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_bin;
```

Dicha llave se compone por dos campos, valga la redundancia y necesito tenerla como foránea en la tabla Alumno; el código que trato de implementar es el siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE `alumno` (
  `Matricula` varchar(15) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `Nombre` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `ApellidoPaterno` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `ApellidoMaterno` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `Id_Grupo` varchar(45) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `Dia` varchar(15) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Matricula`),
      CONSTRAINT `Id_Grupo` FOREIGN KEY (`Id_Grupo`,`Dia`) REFERENCES `detallegrupo` (`Id_Grupo`,`Dia`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_bin;
```

Alguna tendrá una idea del por que me arroja el error?
Gracias anticipadas

Comment: Hay dos problemas en la tabla `alumno`: el primero es que en ella la columna `Id_Grupo` es del tipo `VARCHAR`, mientras que en la otra tabla es del tipo `INT`, **en ambas tablas debe ser del mismo tipo/tamaño**; el segundo es que le estás dando el mismo nombre a la restricción en ambas tablas (ahora no recuerdo , pero me parece que en la misma BD no puede haber nombres de restricciones repetidos, cámbialo en una de las dos... es más, conviene que uses alguna *convención de nombres* también para las restricciones.

Comment: Gracias, he solucionado el problema.

Comment: Me alegro. Si la respuesta que existe fue válida para resolverlo conviene que la marques como aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que la tabla `detallehorario` no necesita cambios, podrías probar algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE `alumno` (
  `Matricula` varchar(15) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `Nombre` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `ApellidoPaterno` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `ApellidoMaterno` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `Id_Grupo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Dia` varchar(15) COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Matricula`),
      CONSTRAINT `Id_Grupo_Fk` FOREIGN KEY (`Id_Grupo`,`Dia`) REFERENCES `detallehorario` (`Id_Grupo`,`Dia`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_bin;
```

Tres cambios:
 1. Tipo de dato en Id_Grupo: `varchar` por `int`
 2. Nombre del constraint: `Id_Grupo` por `Id_Grupo_Fk`
 3. Tabla de referencia de la llave compuesta: `detallegrupo` por `detallehorario`